# Reset IP counter used by docker

Tags: docker

I start, stop and remove containers as part of a continuous build process. Each time the build runs, the containers get new IPs.

Im already at `172.17.0.95` after starting at `172.17.0.2` an hour back.

Since I remove old containers each build, I would also like to reset the IP counter, so that I dont have a timebomb where I run out of IP addresses after say a few hundred builds.

Please let me know how I can let the entity (DHCP Server?) know that IPAddress is free again, and to reset counter.

Thanks in advance SO community!

Comment: I don't think you will run out of ip addresses.  I think Docker will simply start re-assigning from the beginning once it reaches the end of the range.  Unless you have actually run into a problem, I wouldn't waste time worrying about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker seems to default to using `172.17.0.0/16` for the `docker0` interface. That's 255^2 addresses, and if you use 100 every hour you'll run through them all in just over 27 days. I think Docker is just being conservative in not recycling them faster, but will loop around when it reaches the end.

If you need a bigger or different address space, you can use the `--bip` and `--fixed-cidr` flags on the Docker server to choose your own CIDR. [See the Docker documentation on networking here.](http://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#customizing-docker0)

If you really just want to reset the counter, you would need to restart the docker server. This will have the side-effect of terminating all your running containers.

Comment: When you say restart the docker server, you mean the docker daemon right? Is `sudo restart docker` sufficient to do this? I accept the fact that it will terminate running containers.

Comment: Yes, the docker daemon. It depends on what you're using for initd, but on Ubuntu (for example) you'd do `sudo service docker restart`